# Multiple "match" checks in one stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is it possible to check if an array (or collection) contains element 5 **and** element other than 5. In **one** stream returning boolean result instead of using two streams:

```
int[] ints = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

boolean hasFive = IntStream.of(ints).anyMatch(num -> num == 5);
boolean hasNonFive = IntStream.of(ints).anyMatch(num -> num != 5);

boolean result = hasFive && hasNonFive;
```

Answer (score 6):

In this specific case, i.e. you want to know whether a stream or array contains both, a matching and a nonmatching element (an element matching the predicate’s negation), you can do it much simpler.

First, test whether the first element matches the predicate or its negation, then, search whether the stream contains any match of the opposite:

```
IntPredicate predicate=i -> i==5;

if(ints.length>0 && predicate.test(ints[0]))
    predicate=predicate.negate();
boolean result = IntStream.of(ints).anyMatch(predicate);
```

That’s it. In case you don’t have an array or collection as the stream source, but an arbitrary stream, testing the first element is a bit trickier:

```
IntPredicate[] tmp={ null };
Spliterator.OfInt sp=intStream.spliterator();
boolean result = sp.tryAdvance(
    (int i) -> tmp[0]=predicate.test(i)? predicate.negate(): predicate)
 && StreamSupport.intStream(sp, false).anyMatch(tmp[0]);
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's two solutions involving my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library. The core feature I'm using here is the concept of short-circuiting collectors. My library enhances the `Collector` concept to provide the ability to short-circuit (which works both for sequential and parallel streams)

If predicates are like in your sample (one is the opposite of another), you may use `partitioningBy`:

```
Map<Boolean, Optional<Integer>> map = IntStreamEx.of(ints).boxed()
        .partitioningBy(num -> num == 5, MoreCollectors.first());
```

Now you should check whether both mappings are present:

```
System.out.println(map.values().stream().allMatch(Optional::isPresent));
```

Or in single statement:

```
System.out.println(IntStreamEx.of(ints).boxed()
        .partitioningBy(num -> num == 5, MoreCollectors.first())
        .values().stream().allMatch(Optional::isPresent));
```

Here we're using [`MoreCollectors.first()`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/MoreCollectors.html#first--) short-circuiting collector. This solution is similar to one proposed by @user140547, but it will actually stop processing as soon as both elements are found.

---

For two custom predicates it's possible to use [`pairing`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/MoreCollectors.html#pairing-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.BiFunction-) collector which combines the results of two collectors (preserving the short-circuiting if input collectors are short-circuiting). But first, we need `anyMatching` collector (which is absent in my library):

```
import static one.util.streamex.MoreCollectors.*;

static <T> Collector<T, ?, Boolean> anyMatching(Predicate<T> pred) {
    return collectingAndThen(filtering(pred, first()), Optional::isPresent);
}

Collector<Integer, ?, Boolean> hasFive = anyMatching(num -> num == 5); 
Collector<Integer, ?, Boolean> hasNonFive =  anyMatching(num -> num != 5);
Collector<Integer, ?, Boolean> hasBoth = pairing(hasFive, hasNonFive, 
          (res1, res2) -> res1 && res2);

System.out.println(IntStreamEx.of(ints).boxed().collect(hasBoth));
```

Answer (score 5):

One way I see how to do that is to create a custom `IntPredicate` from multiple `IntPredicate`s. Each time a value is tested, we try to find a predicate from this array that matches it and if it does, we store it inside an internal `Set` (to handle duplicates correctly). When the stored set has the same size as the initial array, it means all the predicates have been matched and our custom predicate can return `true`.

My initial solution used a `Set<Integer>` to store the indexes of the predicates that were matched. As @Holger commented, it may be more performant to use a `BitSet` and store the indexes of the unmatched predicates.

```
private static class MultipleIntPredicate implements IntPredicate {

    private IntPredicate[] predicates;
    private BitSet unmatchedPredicates;

    public MultipleIntPredicate(IntPredicate... predicates) {
        this.predicates = predicates;
        unmatchedPredicates = new BitSet(predicates.length);
        unmatchedPredicates.set(0, predicates.length, true); // initially, all predicates are unmatched
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(int value) {
        unmatchedPredicates.stream()
                           .filter(i -> predicates[i].test(value))
                           .findFirst()
                           .ifPresent(unmatchedPredicates::clear); // when a match is found, clear the BitSet
        return unmatchedPredicates.isEmpty(); // return true if all the predicates were matched
    }

}
```

Using it like this:

```
int[] ints = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
MultipleIntPredicate predicate = new MultipleIntPredicate(num -> num == 5, num -> num != 5);
boolean hasFiveAndNonFive = IntStream.of(ints).anyMatch(predicate);
System.out.println(hasFiveAndNonFive);
```

For the case of an array, like in your question, this solution is probably more overhead than iterating over the array twice. However, in the case of an infinite `IntStream`, this predicate will still work correctly. It also has the advantage that the wanted predicates do not have to be opposite of themselves.

Comment: Well this solution uses a mutable `BitSet`, would it not better to avoid that as the whole Stream API is about avoid mutable state?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a boxed stream and 2 predicates are enough, you can use `Collectors.partitioningBy` and just do something like:

```
    Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> collect = IntStream.of(ints).boxed().collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(x -> x == 5));

    boolean hasFive = !collect.get(true).isEmpty();
    boolean hasNonFive = !collect.get(false).isEmpty();
```

Another solution (for multiple predicates) which is maybe not as performant  as Tunaki's solution and probably creates too many arrays, but does not use a mutable `BitSet`...

```
    Boolean[] result = IntStream.of(ints).mapToObj(i ->
                    new Boolean[]{four.test(i), five.test(i), six.test(i)}
    ).reduce(new Boolean[]{false, false, false}, Test::or);
```

Comment: Since you are only interested in whether there are elements of either partition, you may use `Collectors.partitioningBy(x -> x == 5, Collectors.counting()))` to avoid unnecessary storage of the elements into `List`s and just check via `collect.get(true)!=0` and `collect.get(false)!=0`. Note that if you use `groupingBy` instead of `partitioningBy`, non-existent groups are simply absent in the resulting `Map` and you can simply check via `collect.containsKey(true)` resp. `collect.containsKey(false)` (or `collect.size()==2` for both)…