# Is it possible to check whether all Java 8 stream elements satify one of given predicates?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

With stream API I could easily check whether all elements satify a given condition, using `allMatch(e -> predicate(e))` method. I could also check if any of multiple conditions is satified `allMatch(e -> predicateA(e) || predicateB(e) || predicateC(e))`. But is it possible to check if all elements satisfy one of those predicates (either one)? In the previous case it is possible that some elements satisfy A and some of them not, but they satisfy B or C (and vice versa).

I could perform `allMatch` multiple times, but then the stream would be terminated and I would need to repeat the preliminary ones.

I could also devise a tricky reduce operation, but then it would not be able to stop earlier, when the result is obviously false (like the `allMatch` method does).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple "match" checks in one stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34219656/multiple-match-checks-in-one-stream)

Comment: In that question, Tagir Valeev's solution should be short-circuiting: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34222362/4945535

Comment: I do not think so - that solution was based on the fact that predicates were easily expressed as `partitioningBy`. Which is not necessary always possible.

Comment: @RadosławŁazarz The question involved 2 opposite predicate as example yes, but some of the answers are more general. The second part of Tagir Valeev's answer is more general and would work whatever 2 predicates. On that post [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34220071/1743880) is also more general, simple, but lacks parallel support.

Comment: Well, right, it's true. Especially your answer is generic enough to cover this problem.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're trying to achieve. Can you write out how you'd solve this running `allMatch` multiple times, to see if there's a way we can simplify it?

Comment: @StuartMarks: As far as I understand it, the goal is to do
`foos.stream().allMatch(predicate1) || foos.stream().allMatch(predicate2)` without creating two streams and maintaining short-circuiting behaviour.

Comment: @user140547: exactly that, with generalization for n>2 predicates case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible approach, that goes back to using a simple `Iterator` over the elements of the Stream (so it doesn't have parallel support, but works for any kind and any number of predicates).

It creates an initial `BitSet` having the size of the given predicates' length with all bits set to `true`, and each time we retrieve a next element, we clear (set to `false`) the indexes of the predicates that didn't match. Thus, at each index, the bit set will contain whether that predicate all matched the element of the stream so far. It is short-circuiting because it loops until there are elements left and the bit set is not empty (meaning there are still predicates that all matched the elements considered so far).

```
@SafeVarargs
private static <T> boolean allMatchOneOf(Stream<T> stream, Predicate<T>... predicates) {
    int length = predicates.length;
    BitSet bitSet = new BitSet(length);
    bitSet.set(0, length);
    Iterator<T> it = stream.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext() && !bitSet.isEmpty()) {
        T t = it.next();
        IntStream.range(0, length).filter(i -> !predicates[i].test(t)).forEach(bitSet::clear);
    }
    return !bitSet.isEmpty();
}
```

Sample usage:

```
// false because not all elements are either even or divisible by 3
System.out.println(allMatchOneOf(Stream.of(2, 3, 12), i -> i % 2 == 0, i -> i % 3 == 0));

// true because all elements are divisible by 3
System.out.println(allMatchOneOf(Stream.of(3, 12, 18), i -> i % 2 == 0, i -> i % 3 == 0));
```

---

If we want to keep parallel support, we can have help from the [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library, that has `filtering`, `first` and `pairing` collectors. We reuse the `anyMatching` collector [wrote in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34222362/1743880).

```
import static one.util.streamex.MoreCollectors.*;

@SafeVarargs
static <T> Collector<T, ?, Boolean> allMatchingOneOf(Predicate<T> first, Predicate<T>... predicates) {
    Collector<T, ?, Boolean> collector = allMatching(first);
    for (Predicate<T> predicate : predicates) {
        collector = pairing(collector, allMatching(predicate), Boolean::logicalOr);
    }
    return collector;
}

static <T> Collector<T, ?, Boolean> allMatching(Predicate<T> pred) {
    return collectingAndThen(anyMatching(pred.negate()), b -> !b);
}

static <T> Collector<T, ?, Boolean> anyMatching(Predicate<T> pred) {
    return collectingAndThen(filtering(pred, first()), Optional::isPresent);
}
```

The new `allMatchingOneOf` collector combines the result of each `allMatching` collecting result by performing a logical OR on it. As such, it will tell whether all elements of the stream matched one of the given predicates.

Sample usage:

```
// false because not all elements are either even or divisible by 3
System.out.println(Stream.of(2, 3, 12).collect(allMatchingOneOf(i -> i % 2 == 0, i -> i % 3 == 0)));

// true because all elements are divisible by 3
System.out.println(Stream.of(3, 12, 18).collect(allMatchingOneOf(i -> i % 2 == 0, i -> i % 3 == 0)));
```

Comment: Note that the collector created by `allMatchingOneOf` should actually short-circuit if the `StreamEx` stream is used as the input. Will work as normal collector with non-streamex stream.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the iterative solution of [Tunaki’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38917133/2711488) to create a functional one which is not short-circuiting, but works in parallel:

```
@SafeVarargs
private static <T> boolean allMatchOneOf(Stream<T> stream, Predicate<T>... predicates) {
    int length = predicates.length;
    return stream.collect( () -> new BitSet(length),
    (bitSet,t) ->
      IntStream.range(0, length).filter(i -> !predicates[i].test(t)).forEach(bitSet::set),
    BitSet::or).nextClearBit(0)<length;
}
```

To simplify the code, this flips the meaning of the bits; setting a bit implies an unmatched predicate. So there’s a predicate fulfilled by all elements, if there is an unset bit within the range. If the predicates are rather expensive, you can use that information to only test predicates still fulfilled by all previous elements:

```
@SafeVarargs
private static <T> boolean allMatchOneOf(Stream<T> stream, Predicate<T>... predicates) {
    int length = predicates.length;
    return stream.collect( () -> new BitSet(length),
        (bitSet,t) -> {
            for(int bit=bitSet.nextClearBit(0); bit<length; bit=bitSet.nextClearBit(bit+1))
                if(!predicates[bit].test(t)) bitSet.set(bit);
        },
        BitSet::or).nextClearBit(0)<length;
}
```

It’s still not short-circuiting, but renders subsequent iterations to no-ops for failed predicates. It may still be unsatisfying if the *source* of the stream elements is expensive.

Note that you can use a similar improvement for the iterative solution:

```
@SafeVarargs
private static <T> boolean allMatchOneOf(Stream<T> stream, Predicate<T>... predicates) {
    int length = predicates.length;
    BitSet bitSet = new BitSet(length);
    bitSet.set(0, length);
    for(Iterator<T> it = stream.iterator(); it.hasNext() && !bitSet.isEmpty(); ) {
        T t = it.next();
        for(int bit=bitSet.nextSetBit(0); bit>=0; bit=bitSet.nextSetBit(bit+1))
            if(!predicates[bit].test(t)) bitSet.clear(bit);
    }
    return !bitSet.isEmpty();
}
```

The iterative solution already was short-circuiting in that it stops when there is no potentially matching predicate left, but still checked all predicates when there was at least one potentially matching predicate. With this improvement, it only checks predicates which have not failed yet and still exits when there is no candidate left.

Answer (score 0):

> I could perform this operation twice, but then the stream would be terminated and I would need to repeat the preliminary ones.

If you intend to process the elements only after checking your conditions then the stream will have to be buffered anyway since the condition can only be checked once all elements have been traversed.

So your options are generating the stream twice or putting it into a collection.

Comment: It's not entirely true. `Stream.of("one", "two", "three").peek(e -> System.out.println(e)).allMatch(e -> e.equals("one"));` will result in printing "one" and "two", because the condition will fail on the second element. Element "three" is not processed.

Comment: what you're observing is just the current behavior, the APIs do not guarantee that, therefore it is not a solution I would suggest.

Comment: It does not guarantee it, because it depends on the exact predicate and whether the source stream is infinite. But it is a short-circuiting terminal operation and tries to not process all elements if it is not necessary (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-). Also allowing to sometimes process infinite streams in finite time.

Comment: I think we may be talking about different things. Do you actually want to consume the contents of the stream *after* checking whether all of its elements one or the other condition?

Comment: Yes, but in order to check the conditions I need to preprocess each of the elements. Therefore if, after processing a few first elements, each of the predicates failed on at least one of them there is no need for further processing - it will be efficient to immediately return false.

Comment: yes, but that still means buffering or iterating twice in the case when it does match, which is what i'm referring to.