# check if all Objects of a stream meet a rule

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I want to check if all objects of a stream meet a rule, and returns True only if all of them meets the rule,
but I have a compilation error: `Role cannot be applied to lambda parameter`

```
public static Predicate<Hostel> areAllTrue() {
   return req -> req.getRole().stream(r -> isTrue(r));
}


private static boolean isTrue(HostelRole hostelRole) {

}
```

Comment: `stream(r -> isTrue(r))`, wouldn't compile since it doesn't accept an argument either. Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to check whether all Java 8 stream elements satify one of given predicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38903844/is-it-possible-to-check-whether-all-java-8-stream-elements-satify-one-of-given-p)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the terminal operation `allMatch`:

```
public static Predicate<Hostel> areAllTrue() {
   return req -> req.getRole().stream().allMatch(r -> isTrue(r));
}
```